# Remove multiple keys within a HashMap (Java)

Tags: java, hashmap

Any way to delete multiple keys in one shot?

```
public class AuctionTable extends HashMap<String, Auction> {

public void removeExpiredAuctions() {
    Set<String> keys = this.keySet();
    for (String key : keys) {
            if (this.get(key).getTimeRemaining() == 0) {
                this.remove(key);
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure who's populating the contents of this hashmap, but you might be able to sneak in a callback somewhere that can remove that key from the hashmap when the Time Remaining becomes 0.

Comment: no. even if you would use `this.keySet().removeAll(...)` this would still be one at a time underneath.

Comment: What I mean is that the callback takes care of removing its specific key from the map. That way when multiple values become zero, they start removing keys simultaneously and don't have to do it iteratively by checking values one after the other.  However, you'll have to handle concurrency correctly.
If you think it is risky, then better go with what you've already implemented.

If the map is quite small, the performance should not be a problem. If your map is very large, then maybe it's not a good place to store that data.

Comment: Please post an [MCR](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that someone can help you..

Comment: I honestly just need an example of you removing multiple keys from a hashmap

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're probably looking for the [removeIf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-) which will allow you to remove elements from the HashMap which meet a certain criteria as defined by the predicate passed in.

```
public class AuctionTable extends HashMap<String, Auction> {
    public void removeExpiredAuctions() {
        this.values().removeIf(a -> a.getTimeRemaining() == 0);
    }
}
```

Using this example:

```
        Auction firstAuction = new Auction(100);
        Auction secondAuction = new Auction(0);
        Auction thirdAuction = new Auction(200);
        Auction fourthAuction = new Auction(0);
        AuctionTable table = new AuctionTable();
        table.put("first", firstAuction);
        table.put("second", secondAuction);
        table.put("third",  thirdAuction);
        table.put("fourth", fourthAuction);
        table.removeExpiredAuctions();
        Set <String> keySet = table.keySet();
        System.out.println("keySet after removal = " + keySet);
```

The output is:

> keySet after removal = [third, first]

Comment: Thanks, it works, but can you explain what "a ->" means exactly? Basically explaining the process of this method

Comment: @Fireassassin Take a look at [The Java Tutorial, Lambda Expressions section](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html)